# Unity, 2D, Hiding light sources outside of field of view

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, rendering, game-development, light

I'm playing with light 2D in unity and struggling to achieve proper lighting. I want to create a top down shooter with rendering only field of view of a playable character. I have two light sources in that scene: That yellow rectangle with eyes and a second one on the left in the shadow. My goal is to hide any object which is not in a field of view of that yellow character - even light sources, but to keep the light that's visible, like additional shadow effect,  light effects and so on. Second screen is edited in paint to show what I'm aiming for. Do you know how to achieve that effect?

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQS8F.png)
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xV8E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving an answer because I cannot yet leave a comment. One way I can imagine doing this is by using a 2D line renderer instead of casting shadow from your Yellow Light source. Make the line thick and black and it's placement is defined such that the starting point would be the object (wall, obstacle etc.) and the line will go in opposite direction to some feasible extent of where the Yellow Light source is.